# NSURLSessionへの移植ができない

Tags: swift

NSURLConnectionのsendSynchronousRequestメソッドがiOS9.0で非推奨のため、
警告文にあるような、NSURLSessionのdataTaskWithRequestで同じ処理を行いたいのですが上手くできません。

【Xcode ビルド設定】　
・ iOS Deployment Target → iOS 12.4
・ Swift Language Version → Swift5

【元のソース】

```
let res:Data = try! NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(req as URLRequest, returning: nil)
```

【警告文は下記の通りです】

```
// warning
'sendSynchronousRequest(_:returning:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use [NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:] (see NSURLSession.h
```

【元ソース】のresはData型で受けたいのですがdataTaskWithRequestはData型ではないreturnのためエラーになります。
どのように修正すればよいのでしょうか

Comment: `sendSynchronousRequest`のような同期処理を代替する手段は用意されていません。取得した`Data`をどのように使いたいのでしょうか?その辺までご質問に含められると、より的確な回答が得やすいでしょう。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/211836

Comment: ありがとうございます。同期処理の仕込みは別途実装しないと行けないのですね...